# smarty problem when assign variable

Tags: php, smarty

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in rezultati/index.tpl line 24]: syntax error: $smarty. is an unknown reference (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 2164) in D:\HTTPSERVER\wwwroot\kajak\sistem\smarty\libs\Smarty.class.php on line 1093


{assign var="file" value="{$smarty.const.CMS_URL_POT}/moduli/rezultati/files/{$rezultat.datoteka|ss}"}
            {if file_exists($file)}
                <a href="{$file}" target="_blank">{$smarty.const.REZULTATI_025}</a> 
            {/if}
```

Why this is not valid: `{assign var="file" value="{$smarty.const.CMS_URL_POT}` and `$rezultat.datoteka|ss`. `|ss` is not recogniozed when using assign..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks (instead of braces) around the variable:

```
`$smarty.const.CMS_URL_POT`
```

From the [manual](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl):

> Smarty will recognize assigned
>   variables embedded in "double quotes"
>   so long as the variable name contains
>   only numbers, letters, under_scores
>   and brackets[]. See naming for more
>   detail.
>
> With any other characters, for example
>   a .period or $object>reference, then
>   the variable must be surrounded by
>   backticks.

Comment: Thx i will try. Why to use ` (backticks)?

Comment: @senzacionale: That's just how smarty requires it. It's most likely related to PHP's requiring of braces when interpolating multidimensional arrays in a string. I've added a link to the relevant manual page.

Comment: thx for help. i also found that in manual. What about $rezultat.datoteka|ss. i can not use |ss and backticks. if using just $rezultat.datoteka then works but if i add |ss then not working any more when using assing.

Comment: They show an example: `{func var="test ``$foo.bar`` test"|escape}`

Comment: Whoops. Those should be single backticks in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using `backticks` if you want the constant treated as part of the $smarty variable, take this as an example:

```
{assign var="myvar" value="20"}
{* myCONST = 'test'  - assuming you have a const defined somewhere *}

{assign var="file" value="(`$smarty.const.myCONST`/moduli/rezultati/files/`$myvar`)"}
{$file} {* should return "test/moduli/rezultati/files/20 *}
```

Not exactly sure what you want to achieve but I hope this gives you the idea.